# Facebook API: How do I get the 'Allow Access?' page to display?

Tags: facebook

I want users to add my Facebook Canvas application to their profile. I can create my own page with a 'connect' button to do this, but how do I do this within the canvas page?

What do I mean?

Go to any typical application, usually the first screen you see is an 'Allow Access?' screen with a button for 'Allow' or cancel (link).

How do I get such a screen to display for my canvas application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the API's `require_login()` method.

```
$facebook = new Facebook( ... );
$facebookId = $facebook->require_login();
```

Comment: Yup, that's it, just found that while looking at the footprints demo.

Cheers!